# RuntimeError: wrapped C/C++ object of type QWebEngineDownloadItem has been deleted in PyQt

Tags: pyqt, pyqt5

I wrote a web browser

What I want to do is when I click on the download links, a new window will open to manage the downloads and manage the tasks of starting downloads and stopping downloads in a new window(download manager window)

When I click on the download links,

a new window (download manager window) opens But when I click on the start button in the download manager window, I get this error

`RuntimeError: wrapped C/C++ object of type QWebEngineDownloadItem has been deleted`

#my Code:

```
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtWebEngineWidgets import *
import os
import sys
from functools import partial

class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        self.browser = QWebEngineView()
        self.browser.page().profile().downloadRequested.connect(self.openDownloadManagerWindow)
        self.browser.setUrl(QUrl("http://google.com"))
        self.setCentralWidget(self.browser)
        navtb = QToolBar("Navigation")
        self.addToolBar(navtb)
        self.urlbar = QLineEdit()
        self.urlbar.returnPressed.connect(self.navigate_to_url)
        navtb.addWidget(self.urlbar)
        self.show()
 
    
    #download manager window
    def openDownloadManagerWindow(self , download):
        self.downloadWindow = QDialog()
        self.downloadWindow.resize(400,200)
        self.start_button = QPushButton("Start" , self.downloadWindow)
        self.stop_button = QPushButton("Stop" , self.downloadWindow)
        self.stop_button.move(320,0)
        self.downloadWindow.show()

        self.start_button.clicked.connect(partial(self.start , download))

    def start(self , download):
        download.accept()

    def navigate_to_url(self):
        q = QUrl(self.urlbar.text())
        if q.scheme() == "":
            q.setScheme("http")
        self.browser.setUrl(q)

 

app = QApplication(sys.argv)
window = MainWindow()
app.exec_()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://doc.qt.io/Qt-5/qwebenginedownloaditem.html#object-life-cycle) :

> If `accept()` is not called by any signal handler, then the [QWebEngineDownloadItem] will be deleted immediately after signal emission. This means that the application must not keep references to rejected download items.

So you *need* to accept the download in your `openDownloadManagerWindow`, since it will otherwise be deleted at the end of the function, and cause your application to break.

Comment: This isn't really a solution. There are several other problems that need fixing as well. For example, reconnecting `start_button` for every download is a very bad idea, because it will ***add*** a new connection every time it's called (resulting it multiple slot calls). Instead, the button should be connected to `start` *once* inside `__init__`. Then, inside `openDownloadManagerWindow`, do `self.download = download; self.dowload.accept(); self.download.pause()`. Now the start button can simply call `self.download.resume()`, and the stop button can call `self.download.cancel()`.

Comment: @ekhumoro : you're right, especially about setting up the download window only once in `__init__`. However, I actually tested `self.download = download; self.dowload.accept(); self.download.pause()` thing, and it does not work. The download seems to be started immediately with the `accept`, and `pause` seems to have no effect.

Comment: I did wonder about the timing of the pause. It will probably be necessary to connect to [stateChanged](https://doc.qt.io/Qt-5/qwebenginedownloaditem.html#stateChanged) and wait for `DownloadInProgress` before calling `pause()`.

Comment: I've experimented a bit more, and I tried that too... doesn't seem to do the trick. Calling `accept` immediately starts the download and changes the state to `DownloadInProgess`. i'm guessing `pause` should work immediately after that (and `isPaused()` does return`True` if`pause` is called inside `openDownloadManagerWindow` )? It seems the files I was testing with were finished downloading before `pause` could take effect --  if I request very large files it does actually pause the download ... after downloading several hundred KB.

Comment: This does beg the question though: how do you queue up a download without starting it?

Comment: Actually, the pause does work - it's just that pre-cached files will be copied instantly, leaving nothing to resume. I think the only workable solution will therefore be to use two dialogs. The first will request a destination path using `QFileDialog.getSaveFileName`, which will block the download signal handler until the user chooses. If they don't cancel the file-dialog, call `download.setPath(destpath); download.accept()`, then open the second dialog which has e.g. some pause/resume/cancel buttons and a progress bar.